# Nginx 301 subdomain

Tags: nginx, http-status-code-301

I wanna this function:

```
mydomain.com--->301--->mynewdomain.com
subdomain1.mydomain.com--->301--->subdomain1.mynewdomain.com
subdomain2.mydomain.com--->301--->subdomain2.mynewdomain.com
...............
subdomain*.mydomain.com--->301--->subdomain*.mynewdomain.com
```

so who can give me some nginx configure code.
I have tried this,not working:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name "~^(.*)mydomain.com";
    set $sub_name $1;
    return 301 $scheme://{$sub_name}mynewdomain.com$request_uri ;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a named capture in the `server_name` regular expression. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.

Where a variable name requires braces, use `${ ... }`.

For example:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name ~^(?<sub_name>.*)mydomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://${sub_name}mynewdomain.com$request_uri;
}
```